# Class 'ConsoleTVs\Charts\Facades\Charts' not found not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

Hello all i am use laravel 5.7 , i want use Charts and Graphs. i am 
install ConsoleTVs/Charts composer package,

I get this Exception

> "Class 'ConsoleTVs\Charts\Facades\Charts' not found'"

Comment: try to clear config `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 0):

Selly suggestion but are you using the namespace in the top of the file?
like `use ConsoleTVs\Charts\Facades\Charts`